# attempt to reference a deleted function _ gmock

Tags: c++, googlemock

I'm working for the first time with GMock, I'm mocking a class with pure virtual methods,
I created an instance from the Mock class

```
MockInterface mockIntr;
```

Then I need to pass this mock as a parameter to another function

```
func->action(std::make_shared<MockInterface>(mockIntr);
```

in this case I got the error :
"C2280 : MockInterface::MockInterface(const MockInterface&) : attempt to reference a deleted function"

I'm not sure if the solution is to create a copy constructor in the class MockInterface or there is another way to fix the problem.

Comment: What are the constructor definitions of `MockInterface`?, Is the default copy constructor marked with `delete`?

Comment: the copy constructor is marked as delete in the base class (from which I created the MockInterface)

Comment: Then you have to specify one explicitely (which uses a viable constructor of the base class). It's unusual to inherit interfaces from other classes BTW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not passing *that* mock, you're trying to copy it and pass the copy.
(`make_shared<T>(x)` means "create a new `T` from `x` that we can share", not "let's share `x`".)

Create a shared object immediately:

```
auto mockIntr = std::make_shared<MockInterface>();
func->action(mockIntr);
```